# How to make local Nexus repository be proxy for more public repoistories

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I have set up Nexus as local maven repository, and updated the settings.xml according the the [Guide](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/20943003-Configure-Maven-to-Download-from-Nexus).

It works very well if my dependencies can be found from the well-known public repositories like [MavenCentral](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2).

However, it does *not* work if my dependency needs to be downloaded from a not so well-known repository (if I don't want to define any repository in my project pom.xml) like https://clojars.org/repo.

How could I configure the Nexus or maven to solve my problem?

My maven settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings>

  <pluginGroups>
  </pluginGroups>

  <proxies>
  </proxies>

  <servers>
  </servers>

  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>clojars</id>
          <name>Clojars repository</name>
          <url>https://clojars.org/repo</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

And my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-app</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.flipkart.zjsonpatch</groupId>
            <artifactId>zjsonpatch</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <!-- prevents endPosTable exception for maven compile -->
                    <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the external repos to the profiles/profile/repositories group?

Comment: Yes, please see my full settings.xml and pom.xml. I failed to download the zjsonpatch by above example.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a proxy repository in Nexus repository. Once created, you must to add these new repository to the group **Public Repositories**. Your current settings.xml is pointing to the right url. So, now you will be able to download artifacts from the new repository storing artifacts in your Nexus.

[image: Add new proxy repository]
[image: Group repository]