# How to make Nexus repository have multiple proxy repositories?

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I set up nexus as local maven repository. I want two proxy repositories. One get dependencies from maven central another from [reficio repository](http://repo.reficio.org/maven/).

I created a new proxy repository maven-reficio and added it to the group repository,maven-public. Also I have edited my  settings.xml as seen in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960333/how-to-make-local-nexus-repository-be-proxy-for-more-public-repoistories).

However, I still cannot get the dependencies from reficio repository and dependencies not cached. Please advise.

[Screenshot of my nexus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29odr.png)

My settings.xml :

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <pluginGroups></pluginGroups>
    <proxies></proxies>
    <servers></servers>

    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-public/</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>reficio</id>
                    <name>Reficio repository</name>
                    <url>http://repo.reficio.org/maven/</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>

</settings>
```

Here is my final settings.xml that solved my problem after listening to  khmarbaise:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-public/</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>reficio</id>
          <url>http://repo.reficio.org/maven/</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>reficio</id>
          <url>http://repo.reficio.org/maven/</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: Define the usage of the defined proxy repositories in the maven-public group of Nexus and remove repo.reficio.org from your settings.

Comment: khmarbaise, "remove repo.reficio.org from settings" do you mean the url only or the whole profiles tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configurate the settings.xml like this:

```xml
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

And then configuration other repository in your nexus...